# Android: what's the most simple way to sign APK?

Tags: android, cordova, apk

I tried to sign my APK, using:

> keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore

and

> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore
>   my-release-key.keystore ~/Downloads/android-release-unsigned.apk
>   nickname

But it failed with:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore
>   was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887127/jarsigner-error-java-lang-runtimeexception-keystore-load-keystore-was-tampere)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keytool error Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891182/keytool-error-keystore-was-tampered-with-or-password-was-incorrect)

Comment: I solved my problem, the following link has some answers that helped me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449512/how-to-create-signed-apk-file-using-cordova-command-line-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sign using Android Studio.
If you need a release build then change the build type to release and then go to **Build>Generate signed apk**. Add the necessary details and your apk will be generated along with your keystore file.
For more details please visit [Android Developer Site](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

If you are using eclipse you may visit [This So post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916053/android-application-apk-signing)

Comment: @user6039980 Please edit your question and mention this as people may continue giving the wrong answer.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Build>Generate Signed APK>Next (module selected would be your module , most often called "app") also Check Following link

[Sign Your App](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html)

Comment: I use this option as well. Using Android Studio has been the easiest for me.